# paypal ipn problem, url malformed (sandbox works, paypal doesn't)

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have an IPN file that works perfectly in sandbox. It returns valid or not and executes the code correctly. However if I try real live payments it tells me the url is malformed

This is the error with live payments:

```
bool(false) string(15) " malformed"
```

this is the curl code I have:

```
if($testmode === true)
{
    $paypalaction = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
elseif($paypal == "paypal")
{
    $paypalaction = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   // If magic quotes is enabled strip slashes
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
   {
       $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($value);
       $value = stripslashes($value);
   }
   $value = urlencode($value);
   // Add the value to the request parameter
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$paypalaction); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($res);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please add the full error message you're getting "it tells me the URL is malformed" doesn't ring any bells as an error message.

Comment: it's just above the code if you would read more carefully!

Comment: Apologies; I missed that earlier. I ran your sample and it returned 'INVALID' as expected. Though I'm a bit baffled why you're getting " malformed", and not "$paymentaction malformed". Have a look at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47717 as well

Comment: could this be server related? I have this problem on a clients server and on my own server but on the server of my side company it works without a problem

Comment: Having read up on the error, I'd assume so. Is there a (transparent) proxy in place at either location? What are the PHP versions on all three servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with paypal or sandbox but just me being stupid. i had the following if statement:

```
if($testmode === true)
{
    $paypalaction = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
elseif($paypal == "paypal")
{
    $paypalaction = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
```

But the `$paypal` variable wasn't used anymore so it never entered the `elseif` statement. I should have been only an if else:

```
if($testmode === true)
    {
        $paypalaction = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }
    else
    {
        $paypalaction = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be posting sandbox transactions to the live URL or the other way around. Make sure that when you try a live transaction, you are doing so with a real, live PayPal account. Double-check your code to ensure that your test for which PayPal URL is working correctly.

Comment: thanks for your help, the mistake was ... let's just say i really feel stupid right now